# Saving records to a CSV from python with multiple values assigned to each record

Tags: python, csv

I have begun a project trying to implement case based reasoning in python for use on suggesting products to customers.
I need to save to a file data in this format (These are a representation of Cells of a spreadsheet)

```
OrderID|ItemID|
O1     |i23   |
       |i43   |
       |i24   |
O2     |i24   |
       |i29   |
```

etc.
I cant seem to find any information on using a CSV file in this format. Currently the system which reads requires an order ID on every line in the record. And I have no way of saving data returned by the system like this :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'O1': ['i23', 'i43', 'i24 ']})
```

I Have read through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) on the python CSV library but can't get an understanding of how to go about this. Any help, tips, pointers as to what data type to store the information in would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really a valid CSV format, but we can manually do something approaching it.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as dest:
    writer = csv.writer(dest)
    for key, values in data.items():
        writer.writerow([key, values[0]])
        for value in values[1:]:
            writer.writerow([None, value])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried something similar to this but i only get in the CSV file viewed in excel, in one cell 'O' and the cell next to it '1'?

Comment: Well I don't know what your "something similar" is. Did you try this exact code?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the code which i wrote but I have tried this code exactly and it is behaving as above

Comment: Sorry, tweaked the answer, try it now.

Comment: Ah it works as needed when the loop is ran and output to console however, using the CSV writer it leaves a blank row in between each data  entry ?

Comment: writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n') needs to be used to sort out the line breaks. Thank you so much! lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
In [2]: str = StringIO.StringIO()

In [3]: import csv

In [4]: wr = csv.writer(str)

In [5]: wr.writerow(['a', [1, 2]])

In [6]: str.getvalue()
Out[6]: 'a,"[1, 2]"\r\n'
```